# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. in mvc5 show error in @using in razor

Tags: string, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc5 for application my local system application is working properly. but I upload  publish  file  then server shows error [show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmVGF.png)

[image]

Would be nice if anyone helps about it

Comment: What's the signature of your `Login` action look like?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, it is hard to tell, but at a guess, you may want to look into your config file(s) and particularly the transformation side of this value in app settings.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

It may have an incorrect value which cannot be parsed, which is why the error is occurring down the stack after "get_clientvalidationenabled" is called.